# No rational supremum proof

Tags: proof-verification, supremum-and-infimum

I'm currently in the beginning of a journey of self-studying real analysis, and I tried to prove the following statement:

Prove that the following set does not have a rational supremum:
$$
E=\{x \in \mathbb{Q} \text{ : } x^2 < 2\}
$$

Here is my proof and I would appreciate comments and constructive critics of what I was able to achieve at the moment:

---

Let $\sup{E} = \frac{a}{b}$ be the rational supremum of $E$. First consider the possibility that $\sup{E} \in E$, which implies that $\frac{a^2}{b^2} < 2$. Now let's look to the distance from $\sup{E}$ to $2$:
$$
\frac{a^2}{b^2} < 2 \rightarrow \mid \frac{a^2}{b^2} - 2 \mid > 0
$$
Let's call that distance $d=\mid \frac{a^2}{b^2} - 2 \mid $. With that, we can build a new supremum:
$$
k =\sup{E} + \frac{d}{2}
$$
And clearly $k > \sup{E}$, and that contradicts the fact for $\sup{E}$ to be a supremum.

Now consider the case where $\sup{E} \notin E$, which implies that $\frac{a^2}{b^2} \geq 2$. It's a proven fact that $\sqrt{2}$ is not rational, therefore, by the same reasoning, we define a distance $d=\mid 2 - \frac{a^2}{b^2} \mid $. Still in the same reasoning as before, we can conclude that:
$$
k' = \sup{E} - \frac{d}{2}
$$
And clearly $k' < \sup{E}$, which is a contradiction.

Hence, the conclusion is that the set $E$ does not have a rational supremum.

---

Am I correct? If not, can you please point out what would you change in order to improve my proof?

Thank you, and any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: I did not carefully check the proof yet , but it appears to be valid. The basic idea is in fact that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational and that the rationals are dense in the reals.

Comment: Thank you Peter :)

Comment: Your proof is correct, as @Peter said the key is that $\Bbb{Q}$ is dense in $\Bbb{R}$, so for any $\epsilon > 0$ you can always find a rational in $B(\sqrt{2},\epsilon)$, as you proved. Well done

Comment: Oops.  Misunderstood what the set E was.

Comment: @JoseSquare Thank you mate! I'm still at the beginning of Real Analysis... I've done quite a ton of math courses that are not proof-based, and just two that are proof-based, so I'm preparing myself for my next big undergraduate course, which is Real Analysis. Any tips? Thank you!

Comment: Dover Publications (formerly Dover Press) is still a good source for cheap re-prints of old math texts. E.g. Infinite Sequences And Series by Bromwich, which has no calculus pre-requisite.

Comment: @BrunoReis I recommend you reading a lot of math books, look for the classics, the bad thing is that they are expensive, but maybe you cab find then on libraries. For calculus the Spivak is a good option for begining with Analysis or the Apostol.